# Range value in Dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, html-select

i wanted to know how to view children for each age group (6-10, 11-13, 14-16) in dropdownlist. For example, when i select the age group, the gridview below will only display children for that specified age group.

I converted the date of birth to age using sql below.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100) + DAY(GETDATE()) >= (MONTH(Dob) * 100)
+ DAY(Dob) THEN DATEDIFF(Year, Dob, GETDATE()) ELSE DATEDIFF(Year, Dob, GETDATE())
- 1 END AS Age FROM parent WHERE ([Gender] IS NOT NULL)
```

I have no issues with sql, i am done with converting Date of birth to age but now how to I implement it in age group range ?

[image]

Comment: When you select the age range erase all data in the data grid then loop through everything and check if the age matches the range of which you are looking for. If it matches add it to the data grid.

Comment: I'm just started learning asp.net, don't really understand what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataView.RowFilter` method to filter the data and assign the `DataView` to the `DataGridView.DataSource` properties.

Here's a link on how to use the RowFilter: [DataView.RowFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx)

To populate the DataTable:
[Populating DataTable using SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter)

Then just need to create a new `DataView` with the selected age range each time the user clicks on the `ComboBox`. To revert it to the original unfiltered data, you can assign the `DataTable` as the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView`.